# StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720024

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server and many clients. They are communicating with each other via Java socket. I have made a message library, which contains the messages, that should be sent. A lot of messages works perfectly fine, but there is a problem with one. If I would like to send that kind of message, I get the following exception:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720024
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
>       at messages.MessageHandler.receiveMessageNonBlocking(MessageHandler.java:156)
>       at loadbalancer.socket.SocketCommunicator.socketMessageHandler(SocketCommunicator.java:147)
>       at loadbalancer.socket.SocketCommunicator.run(SocketCommunicator.java:93)

Strage thing that the problem does not occur, if the client and the server runs on the same computer, but it does if they are not. The remote computer uses the same operating system, same Java version.

Do you have any advice about what should I check?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that you are only using `writeObject()` and `readObject()` at both ends, and that you're using the same object streams for the life of the socket, again at both ends. 72730024 has the look of a piece of ASCII text.

Comment: I have already checked that, I am using the same objects at both ends and using only writeObject() and readObject() methods. If I would not use them, the other messages should fail too. Could you tell me where can I check the error codes? I did not know that the  72730024  refers to an ASCII text.

Comment: I have made a fresh start, and the error code changed to : 73720028.

Comment: So you sent something else wrong. Treat the number as hex and look up the ASCII codes. You also need to check that you aren't using any other streams on the same socket.

Comment: It is strange, because it works fine on another computer. I do not know what is wrong with mine, but I will let you and the others know if I have managed to figure it out.